# Treemap with d3: the x, y, dx & dy are NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nan, treemap

A quick question. I have an issue with the d3 treemap method.
When i load this script, all the x are 0 and the console tells me that the y, dy and dx are not numbers.
What did I do wrong ?

```
var colorScale=d3.scale.category10();

var canvas9 = d3.select(".result-side9")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 600)
.attr("height", 600)
.attr("transform","translate(10,10)");

d3.json("assemblee5.json", function (data) {
    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .size(550,550)
        .nodes(data);

    var cells= canvas9.selectAll(".cell")
        .data(treemap)
        .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "cell");

    cells.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d){return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function (d,i){return d.y; })
        .attr("width", function (d,i){return d.dx; })
        .attr("height", function (d,i){return d.dy; })
        .attr("fill", function (d,i){return d.children ? null : colorScale(d.parent.name); })
        .attr("stroke", "white");

    cells.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d,i){return d.x + d.dx/2; })
        .attr("y", function (d,i){return d.y + d.dy/2; })
        .text(function (d){return d.children ? "" : d.name;})
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
});
```

JSonLint tells me that my Json is valid.

Comment: How is your JSON file structured?

Comment: Thanks. There you go.
victoralexandre.fr/assemblee5.json

Comment: Had this same problem This code reflects an older version of D3 (version 3). Here's another example that does the same thing but with the latest version (version 4). https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/379926741d6600ab6c8af7f5f8707373

Version 4 does things in a more comprehendible way to me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your json **is** valid. If you use the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329447) with your json file it works fine.

The one thing I did note was that you aren't defining the 'root', 'nodes' or 'links' of your tree. check out the example at http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329447 and you will note that the process of forming the data for the tree map requires these to be set.

There is a better explanation of it [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html).

EDIT: Ahh.. My bad. I mistook 'Treemap' for 'Tree' Apologies, this answer won't help much. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks. These are examples for trees, and I managed to create trees with the same data but this is a treemap and I don't understand what makes the x, y, dx and dy suddenly become NaN. I have tried the parseInt(d.x) trick... unsuccessfully.

Comment: Hi. Some news. When creating a bar chart, I have an issue with the y and height only. When I recreate the bar chart example from @mbostock from here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304#data.tsv
I get this in the console: 
    Valeur NaN inattendue lors de l'analyse de l'attribut y. d3.min.js:1
    Valeur NaN inattendue lors de l'analyse de l'attribut height.
I run this in Firefox 32.0.3. Could there be some incompatibility?

Comment: Nope. I have some other D3 graphs that are loading fine but I really haven't got a clue why the exact same graph than M.B. would not work and the console would tell me these things with y and height attribute.

Comment: OK. Here's a way to settle this. Create a bl.ock with your code in it and paste the link here. That we mean that we can make sure that there isn't something simple that is tripping you up and we can make an easy comparison with Mike's code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I would love to do this but unfortunately, my computer does not really want me to do it so easily, the installation of hombrew, node and sublime text just don't want to go as planned. SO i thought, would this do: http://victoralexandre.fr/pb-d3_2.html (for the exact example from mbostocks- except for the tsv, csv stuff) and this http://victoralexandre.fr/examplestackoverflow for the treemap

Comment: OK, your bar chart is almost OK, your data file you are asking for in the script is a csv file `donnees/data.csv`, but the data actually *in* the file is tsv. You need to change the name of the file to *.tsv (`donnees/data.tsv`) and change your script to read in tsv (`d3.tsv("donnees/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {`)

Answer (score 0):

In D3, there are layout functions that transform the data into nodes with layout data; dx, dy, x, y, etc added.

If you are using the latest version of D3, version 4 at the time of this writing, then the API is a little different.

This following line from version 3
`d3.layout.treemap()`

In version 4 the line should be:

```
d3.hierarchy(data)
```

Here's a good tutorial on the different layout functions in D3's latest version. Hope that helps. Your layout function may vary depending on what kind of TreeMap you're trying to create. (Partition, vanilla TreeMap, etc.)

http://d3indepth.com/layouts/